# VF page with custom picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Case" controller="customPicklist">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Custom Picklist Using selectList and selectOptions">
  <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCountry2}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!countriesOptions}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>


  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock >

  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

public with sharing class customPicklist {
public String selectedCountry2{get;set;}
public List<String> selectedCategories { get; set; }

public List<SelectOption> getCountriesOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> countryOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('INDIA','India'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('USA','USA'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('United Kingdom','UK'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('Germany','Germany'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('Ireland','Ireland'));

        return countryOptions;
    }


    public List<SelectOption> getCategories() {

       List<SelectOption> categories = new List<SelectOption>();

       for(Case c : [Select sahi__MultiSelectPicklist__c from Case limit 10])

           categories.add(new SelectOption(c.sahi__MultiSelectPicklist__c, c.sahi__MultiSelectPicklist__c));

       return categories;

    }

}
```

I had created a custom picklist, I'm not getting how to display the selected picklist value. Need your valueable inputs. Thanks in advacance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this now:

```
  <apex:page tabStyle="Case" controller="customPicklist">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Custom PickList Demo" id="out">
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="out" status="actStatusId"/>
            <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <img src="/img/loading.gif" />
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Custom Picklist Using selectList and selectOptions">
  <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCountry2}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!countriesOptions}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
<apex:outputText value="{!selectedCountry2}" label="You have selected:"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>


  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock >

  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

public with sharing class customPicklist {
public String selectedCountry2{get;set;}
public List<String> selectedCategories { get; set; }

public List<SelectOption> getCountriesOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> countryOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('INDIA','India'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('USA','USA'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('United Kingdom','UK'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('Germany','Germany'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('Ireland','Ireland'));

        return countryOptions;
    }


    public List<SelectOption> getCategories() {

       List<SelectOption> categories = new List<SelectOption>();

       for(Case c : [Select sahi__MultiSelectPicklist__c from Case limit 10])

           categories.add(new SelectOption(c.sahi__MultiSelectPicklist__c, c.sahi__MultiSelectPicklist__c));

       return categories;

    }
    public PageReference save(){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: and i tried to create multi picklist getCategories(){},how to cal  an how to display the multiple selected values